# Are Xbox One games region locked?

Tags: xbox-one

If I buy an Xbox One from the United States, then go to Thailand will games that I buy in Thailand work for my US Console?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I have been doing research on this (regioned games) myself for a while as I am from the US but I live part time in Germany. Here are my findings:

- XBox 360 games are regioned (NTSC, etc.) so games don't work everywhere
- XBox One games are no longer regioned so games will work everywhere
- *However* Blu-ray DVDs are still regioned, so if you try to watch Blu-ray movies from Thailand on your XBox it will not work

Comment: Not all Xbox 360 games are region locked and not all region-locked 360 games can't work on consoles from a different country/region.